# DVD recorder based on freebsd, how to edit service disc

Tags: freebsd, compiling, binary, reverse-engineering

I am trying to understand what is written here and how it can be done. Maybe someone will be able to help and understand this:

https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/306345-some-problem-with-DVR560H-s-HDD-replacement#post1906393

This is probably a method to remove the disk size limit that a DVD writer can use after initialize HDD, prevent to change hdd to bigger size.

GGV disc:
https://archive.org/details/pioneer-ggv-1321-type-2

This iso must be burn on dvd disc and loading in dvd recorded to initialize new HDD.

Question is how **"remark* reCompile Kernel and rc.local edit it GGV disk"**.

Thank you.

Comment: If `grep quota /etc/fstab` prints nothing for you, then the link you provided is not relevant at all.

Comment: Also, this question is an example of XY problem. Don't ask how to do Y, instead explain what is X. What are you trying to do in the first place?